# C++ data access benchmark

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I`m writing simple benchmark on C++ to compare the execution time of data access on different platforms.And I`ve got strange results. I measure the time of sequential order access and indirection order access. For this I am just copying one array data to another in two different ways. The code and result are below.
The time I got is ambiguous. Evaluation for int data type shows, that sequential access is faster (it is OK). But for float and double types it is just the opposite (see time results below). Maybe I make benchmarking wrong or there are some pitfalls I did not take into account? Or could you suggest some benchmark tools to compare data access or simple operations performance for different datatypes?

```
template<typename T>
std::chrono::nanoseconds::rep PerformanceMeter<T>::testDataAccessArr()
{
    std::chrono::nanoseconds::rep totalSequential = 0;

    T* arrDataIn = new T[k_SIZE];
    T* arrDataOut = new T[k_SIZE];

    std::generate_n(arrDataIn, k_SIZE, DataProcess<T>::valueGenerator);
    DataProcess<T>::clearCache();

    std::chrono::nanoseconds::rep timeSequential = measure::ns(copySequentialArr, arrDataIn, arrDataOut, k_SIZE);

    std::cout << "Sequential order access:\t" << timePrint(timeSequential) << "\t";
    std::cout.flush();

    std::chrono::nanoseconds::rep totalIndirection = 0;
    T** pointers = new T*[k_SIZE];
    T** pointersOut = new T*[k_SIZE];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < k_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        pointers[i] = &arrDataIn[i];
        pointersOut[i] = &arrDataOut[i];
    }

    std::generate_n(arrDataIn, k_SIZE, DataProcess<T>::valueGenerator);
    std::generate_n(arrDataOut, k_SIZE, DataProcess<T>::valueGenerator);

    DataProcess<T>::clearCache();

    totalIndirection = measure::ns(copyIndirectionArr, pointers, pointersOut, k_SIZE);

    std::cout << std::endl << "Indirection order access:\t" << timePrint(totalIndirection) << std::endl;
    std::cout.flush();

    delete[] arrDataIn;
    delete[] arrDataOut;
    delete[] pointers;
    delete[] pointersOut;

    return timeSequential;
}

template <typename T>
void PerformanceMeter<T>::copySequentialArr(const T* dataIn, T* dataOut, size_t dataSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        dataOut[i] = dataIn[i];
}

template <typename T>
void PerformanceMeter<T>::copyIndirectionArr(T** dataIn, T** dataOut, size_t dataSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        *dataOut[i] = *dataIn[i];
}
```

**Results:**

-------------------Measure int---------------

data: 10 MB ; iterations: 1

Sequential order access:        8.50454ms

Indirection order access:       11.6925ms

-------------------Measure float------------

data: 10 MB ; iterations: 1

Sequential order access:        8.84023ms

Indirection order access:       8.53148ms

-------------------Measure double-----------

data: 10 MB ; iterations: 1

Sequential order access:        5.57747ms

Indirection order access:       3.72843ms

Comment: _"iterations: 1"_ Do more iterations and calculate the average time.

Comment: Micro benchmarking is non-trivial. You should add more iterations, include optimizations, and even better look at the assembly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i also did 10 and 20 iterations, and results are the same.

Comment: The namings are a bit confusing, both are sequential...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes, thanks for comment, i should rename it

Comment: @Jonas thanks, but what did you mean about "include optimizations"?

Comment: Compile it in "release mode", or simply add `-O3` to your compiler options (for clang and gcc).

Comment: 10-20 iterations is not enough.  You should be doing 10's or 100's of thousands of iterations.

Comment: @Jonas i`ll try, thank you :)

Comment: @NathanOliver ok, thanks:)

Comment: 100000? What a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are an example (using `T = int`) of the assembly output from GCC 6.3 using `-O2`: 
[`copySequentialArr`](https://godbolt.org/g/3l7Sri) and [`copyIndirectionArr`](https://godbolt.org/g/79YbM0).

From the assembly it is clear that they are very much alike, but `copyIndirectionArr` requires two `mov` instructions more than `copySequentialArr`. With this we can somewhat conclude that `copySequentialArr` is the fastest.

The same it true when using `T = double`: [`copySequentialArr`](https://godbolt.org/g/0GLvxH) and [`copyIndirectionArr`](https://godbolt.org/g/XQ1aBJ).

**Vectorization**

It gets funny when we start using `-O3`: [`copySequentialArr`](https://godbolt.org/g/sB9X2j) and [`copyIndirectionArr`](https://godbolt.org/g/4DJTkJ).
There is no change to `copyIndirectionArr`, but `copySequentialArr` is now vectorized by the compiler. This vectorization will make it even faster than before, under normal conditions.

**Disclainmer**

These examinations of the resulting assembly code are "out-of-context", in the sense that the compiler would optimize it even further if it has knowledge of the context.